# What does it mean when a recruiter says he wanted to connect with me and see my upcoming availability for the next few months?

Tags: interviewing, email

I just had an interview yesterday, and the recruiter sent me an email saying they wanted to connect with me after the interview and see my upcoming availability. How should I reply? Are they asking if I'm available to be contacted? Should I ask how and when he would like to further discuss this?

Comment: It means exactly as he said. He will contact you for job opportunities that he probably believes you qualified for. Recruiters work in weeks-months. Although they hope to placed you in days. The recruiter that got me my current job worked for a period of 2-3 hours in a span of 2 days and I got the job.

Comment: So how should I reply to this?

Comment: Depends. Do you like him and want to work with him? If so, just say "Looking forward to it" but if you believe that you won't like his agency, then just politely say "No thank you".

Answer (score 4):

They want to keep you in their pipeline in case something comes up.

It is his job to fill positions. You are the "filling" - handy for him to have as many of *you* ready as he can, it does not cost anything at this point.

How you should reply: Do you want to get offers?: -> **Yes**, if not then -> **No**

But don´t wait for them if you are currently seeking a job. May very well never come up with a suitable position.